# C# class using subclass does not implement inherited abstract member error

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding

Here's the c# code I'm trying to compile 
Fairly simple, `testDMO` that inherits from `testDMOBase`
Then test that inherits from testBase

```
public abstract class testDMOBase { }
public class testDMO : testDMOBase { }
public abstract class testBase
{
    abstract protected void LoadCRUD(testDMOBase dmo);
}
public class test : testBase
{
    override protected void LoadCRUD(testDMO dmo) { }
}
```

I'm getting the following errors:

> 'test' does not implement inherited abstract member
>   'testBase.LoadCRUD(testDMOBase)' 'test.LoadCRUD(testDMO)': no suitable
>   method found to override

Shouldn't the use of a subclass be ok on the override method?

Answer (score 5):

> Shouldn't the use of a subclass be ok on the override method?

No. Aside from anything else, which implementation would you expect to be called if the caller provided an instance *other* than your subclass?

```
testBase t = new test();
t.LoadCRUD(new SomeOtherDMO()); // What would be called here?
```

You might well argue that it would make sense to be able to override the base method with a subclass method which is *more general* (e.g. with a parameter which is a *superclass* of the original parameter type, or with a return type which is a subclass of the original return type) but .NET doesn't allow either of these anyway. The parameter and return types of the overriding method have to match the original method *exactly*, at least after generic type parameter substitution.

It sounds like you *may* want to make your base type generic:

```
public abstract class TestBase<T> where T : TestDmoBase
{
    public abstract void LoadCrud(T dmo);
}

public class Test : TestBase<TestDmo>
{
    public override void LoadCrud(TestDmo dmo)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that you should follow .NET naming conventions, too - even in sample code.

Comment: Thanks for you advice.  That's what I'll use.

Answer (score 4):

No, in this case you have to **exactly** follow the signature of the `abstract` method, in order to provide valid override.

So, you have to write:

```
public class test : testBase
{
    override protected void LoadCRUD(testDMOBase dmo)  //BASE CLASS
    { }
}
```

Comment: Is there another way to do what I'm trying?

Comment: @RonaldBastien: I think Skeet already provided good example on generics, how that potentially can be handled.

Comment: @RonaldBastien To answer that, we'd need to know exactly what you're trying. What type of `testDMOBase` are you going to be passing to `testBase.LoadCRUD()` ?

Comment: Thanks, I'll use the advice from Jon and make my base type generic.

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't the use of a subclass be ok on the override method?

No, method overrides must use the same parameter types as their original declarations.

Comment: Not to be a jerk, but there are already two answers that say this exact thing. This answer adds nothing to the conversation, and only clutters the list of answers.