# Another "Does Not Inherited Abstract Member"

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding

I'm having a silly C# problem. But keep in mind I'm going from Java to C# **(although I expected overriding methods to be fairly easy)**.

I have two classes right now, the base class *GameState*, and the subclass *GameStateMenu*.

The GameState class

```
namespace Bejeweled.State
{
    abstract class GameState
    {
        private bool visible;

        public abstract void Update();

        public abstract void Draw();

// More code is hidden down here.
```

And my GameStateMenu class

```
namespace Bejeweled.State
{
    class GameStateMenu : GameState
    {
        public override void Update()
        {
        }

        public override void Draw()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I can't get *GameStateMenu* to stop complaining about the following:

> 'Bejeweled.State.GameStateMenu' does not implement inherited abstract member 'Bejeweled.State.GameState.Update()'

I've been Googling like crazy, and the closest resource to my problem has been [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186927/c-sharp-class-using-subclass-does-not-implement-inherited-abstract-member-error), but it still didn't help.

Am I still doing something wrong that I haven't caught? Is Visual Studio complaining for no reason?

Sorry for this silly minuscule error; any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That should work (and indeed does, when I try it). You'll need to post a full example that fails (e.g. a console app that demonstrates the problem).

Comment: the GaneStateMenuClass should also override the Draw function. This code does not work by default.

Comment: Can you verify that this code is the code you're trying to compile **and** that the compiler error is correct? That the compiler error does not say `Draw`, but does indeed say `Update`? I ask because the code as posted should definitely not produce that specific compiler error. It should complain about `Draw`, not `Update`. Please verify?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I was just using the `Update()` method as the example. It was giving an error for both. Verifying this by compiling solved the issue. My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lasse V. Karlsen suggested, it was just the compiler being silly, and not checking itself. A run verified this mistake that was absolutely unnecessary.

My apologies for the unnecessary waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

All abstract methods of an Abstract class should be override so you should override the Draw() also in derived class like this

```
abstract class GameState
{
    private bool visible;

    public abstract void Update();

    public abstract void Draw();
}
class GameStateMenu : GameState
{
    public override void Update()
    {
    }
    public override void Draw()
    {
    }
}
```

If you doesn't really want's to make Draw() method as overridden, you can just remove abstract prefix from Draw() method in GemState base class and provide default implementation like this.

```
abstract class GameState
{
    private bool visible;

    public abstract void Update();

    public void Draw() 
    { 
    }
}
class GameStateMenu : GameState
{
    public override void Update()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I overrode my draw method, too, but that made no difference, so I just used update () as an example of my problem. Doing that hasn't solved my problem